# ¿Cómo usar useRef en un .map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

quería saber si es posible usar useRef en un .map, en este código mi intención es que en cada input al introducir un texto, ese texto sustituya al nombre del usuario. Por otro lado para que muestre el input cuando se hace click en el botón de editar he tenido que crear un estado llamado editMode y de esta manera consigo que se muestre. Si borro ese estado el input no se muestra cuando hago click en el botón editar. Querría saber si esto está bien o se puede hacer de otro forma mejor. Dejo el código a continuación.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

const Examplecomp = () => {
  const users = [
    { name: "Daniel", edit: false },
    { name: "Jaime", edit: false },
    { name: "Manuel", edit: false },
    { name: "Cristina", edit: false },
    { name: "María", edit: false },
    { name: "Laura", edit: false },
  ];

  const [data, setData] = useState(users);
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);

  const selectedUser = useRef();

  const userEdit = (id) => {
    setEditMode(!editMode);
    data[id].edit = !data[id].edit;
  };

  const saveChanges = (id) => {
    if (selectedUser.current.value === "") {
    } else {
      let arrayUsers = data;

      arrayUsers[id].name = selectedUser.current.value;

      setData(arrayUsers);
    }
    setEditMode(!editMode);
    data[id].edit = !data[id].edit;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((element, id) =>
        data[id].edit ? (
          <div key={id}>
            <h2>{element.name}</h2>
            <input key={id} type="text" ref={selectedUser}></input>
            <button onClick={saveChanges}>Cambiar nombre</button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div key={id}>
            <h2>{element.name}</h2>
            <button onClick={() => userEdit(id)}>Editar</button>
          </div>
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Examplecomp;
```

También podéis ver el código aquí si os resulta mas fácil: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-flower-y470l3?file=/src/components/Examplecomp.jsx

Answer (score 1):

El código está bien, el problema está es en el submit del botón para cambiar el nombre...

Cambialo de esto:

```
<button onClick={saveChanges}>Cambiar nombre</button>
```

A esto:

```
<button onClick=={() => saveChanges(id)}>Cambiar nombre</button>
```

Pues tu funcion saveChanges recibe un id y no se lo estás pasando a esa función

Comment: Ahora esa parte funciona bien, gracias. Pero sigo teniendo un problema. Cuando hago click en el botón editar en 2 o más elementos, al hacer click en el botón cambiar nombre, el primero se cambia pero cuando hago click en el segundo me muestra este error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')` y señala esta parte del código  ` if (selectedUser.current.value === "")`